# Unauthorized error when trying to access Heroku Postgres add-on from the Heroku dashboard

Tags: postgresql, heroku, travis-ci

I have a Heroku with Travis CI integrated deployed successfully and I can access the Heroku postgres database from the CLI but whenever I try to access the database from the Heroku dashboard, I'm receiving:

```
{
  "error": {
    "id": "unauthorized",
    "message": "Invalid credentials provided."
  }
}
```

It's strange because everything else is working fine all the way from Github Travis testing (which are all passing), continuous integration, and all the way to Heroku deployments but for some reason I can't seem to access the Postgres db from the dashboard:

[image]

I thought maybe it was an authentication issue but I can access the db from the terminal. Has anyone come across this before?

Answer (score 1):

This must have been an issue internally with Heroku because after 24 hours, it started to give me access. I didn't change any settings so it's difficult for me to say exactly what changed on their end but I would recommend, if someone else has this issue, to contact Heroku customer support.